# How to access directly to files in application directory in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, external-js

I have a folder in my view inside application directory that contain .js files. I want to load .js files in my view. How can do this?

Comment: where is your code and try?

Comment: I added a tag, but this question will need more editing because, in its current state, it is low-quality.

Answer (score 1):

its not a good practice to put your js files in view folder, make a folder called 'assets' in the root directory alongside 'application' and 'system' put all js code in js folder.

- assets 
  --css
  --js 
  -- images
- system
- application